# Understanding format of RIB dumps from Oregon Route-views

Tags: networking, routes, bgp

I am working on a project in which I need to analyse the rib-dumps from the [Oregon Routeviews Project](http://archive.routeviews.org/).

I download the .bz2 file from [here](http://archive.routeviews.org/route-views.chicago/bgpdata/2020.03/RIBS/) for a specific time and date for a specific node. These files are generated every 2 hours.
Then I unzipped and parsed using a [zebra parser](https://github.com/rfc1036/zebra-dump-parser).
In the end, I get a text file with almost a million entries in the following format

194.33.63.0/24 58511 8468 31493 31493

There are also a lot of entries with the same last number but different IP in the beginning.
For example

194.28.28.0/22 58511 31500 50911

194.28.28.0/23 58511 31133 50911

My inference is that these numbers are Autonomous System numbers and they somehow denote BGP Hops, but I am not clear how they relate to the IP address in the starting. And what exactly is the source/destination AS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think you should go and do some reading on how BGP works and what the routeing information carried by the BGP messages you are looking at is and means.

To get you started...

...a *route* in BGP speak is a *prefix* and some *attributes*.  Key among the *attributes* are the *next-hop* and the *AS-Path*.  In announcing a route to a BGP peer (neighbour) the BGP router is saying that it *can* reach the *prefix* and if packets with destinations in the *prefix* are forwarded to the *next-hop*, they *will* be forwarded on towards their destination.  The *AS-PATH* lists the *AS*es through which packets are (expected to) travel on their way to the destination.

So what you are seeing is reachable *prefixes* and the *AS-PATH* attribute for each one.  I'm guessing you left out the *next-hop* (for eBGP, that will generally be the/an address of the BGP router which is advertising the route -- but in any case all eBGP routes will generally have the same *next-hop*).

The *AS-PATH* can be read from left to right: the first *AS* is the one from whom the route was learnt, the last *AS* is the one that contains the *prefix*.  Packets forwarded to the *next-hop* are (currently) expected to travel through those *AS*es, in that order, on their way to their destination.  So the first *AS* would be the source -- the immediate source of the route.  The last *AS* can be called the destination, but is also known as the origin -- the origin of the route.

[Technically, the *AS-Path* should be read from right to left, and lists the *AS*es which the route has traversed this far.  Most of the time that's the same as reading left to right for packets traversing the network towards their destination.]

Answer (score 0):

```
as-50911 origin or destination,
as-58511 source
194.28.28.0/22 should be the owner of as-50911 origin
```

I think you are confused about /23 or /22. 194.28.28.0/23 its not different IP. Its actually the same IP with different prefix length, i.e., /23. The autonomous systems registered their IP addresses with prefix lengths in IRR. Less specific, i.e., /22 means more end node. More specific, i.e., /23 means less end node. Moreover, You should read about prefix length.